# Solve the differential equation $\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y-1)^3-1 $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am struggling with the following differential equation so any help would be much appreciated!

Solve $\frac{dy}{dx}=(x+y-1)^3-1 $ by rewriting $z = x + y -1$  and solving for $z$ and then determining a transformation for a solution in terms of $y$.

Cheers!

Comment: In my (apparently minority) opinion, this is exactly the sort of question where you should provide a hint, and then let user61601 do some work.  Instead, we got a complete solution after just 7 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then we have $\frac{dz}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx}=1-\frac{dz}{dx}$

Plgging this into the original equation we have, 
$$\frac{dz}{dx}=z^3$$
$$\frac{dz}{z^3}=dx$$
On integrating we have,
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{z^2}=-2x+c$$
$$\Rightarrow\frac{1}{(x+y-1)^2}=-2x+c$$
$$1=(-2x)(x+y-1)^2+c(x+y-1)$$

Comment: U are welcome @user61601